# Which has the correct question tag: "They say she speaks Russian, don't they/doesn't she?"

Tags: pronouns, phrase-choice, tag-questions

Which of the two following examples has the correct question tag?

> a) They say she speaks Russian, don't they?

or,

> b) They say she speaks Russian, doesn't she?

Comment: Only a) is correct. A tag seeks confirmation of what is said in the main clause. Here it is asking for confirmation of what they say, not whether she speaks Russian.

Comment: @BillJ: I'm not convinced. I'd say it's a matter of semantics, in that in (a) the speaker appends a question tag inviting confirmation that what they say *("She speaks Russian")* is true, but in (b) he's simply reporting what they said *inclusive* of question tag *("She speaks Russian, doesn't she?")*. It just that there are probably more contexts where (a) would apply than (b).

Comment: But as written, I think the second example should be "They say she speaks Russian. Doesn't she?" to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

The question tag questions the assertion.  So you must identify the assertion. It is identified below in bold:

> **She speaks Russian**, doesn't she?
>
> **They say she speaks Russian**, don't they?

```
It is simple, isn't it?
They say it is simple, _____________?
```

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct, but the underlying question is different.

> They say he writes poetry, don't they?

Here the question iss me asking whether **they** really say this.

> They say, "He writes poetry, doesn't he?"

I've added the quotes to clarify.  Now they are asking whether **he** writes poetry.

Comment: No problems with one sentence tag,  the doubt was related to two clause tags

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a complex sentence with a subordinate clause, you should consider **the main clause** in order to make a tag question:

> *They say*(that) she speaks Russian,don't they?

Comment: even more understandable